# Crosh Shell as default New Tab page

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-os, chromebook, crosh

I run crouton on my chromebook and use the Crosh shell pretty frequently. Is there any way to specify Crosh as the default New Tab on a Chromebook?

I already attempted using the Crosh extension location as the New Tab URL (chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/crosh.html) but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have your own extension? If not create it, with a manifest.json file like this:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Crosh Newtab",
 "version": "1",
 "chrome_url_overrides" : {
  "newtab": "main.html"
 }
}
```

Create main.js and add it to main.html. In main.js, open Crosh and close the current window, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
 url: "chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/crosh.html" 
}, function() { window.close() })
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't answer your question directly, but you could bookmark the crosh URL and pin it to your taskbar, then access it using shortcuts like Alt+3 (where "3" is the 3rd icon in the taskbar).